# Mongoose Async Issues

Tags: json, mongoose

let's say I have this Schema:

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
name: Schema.Types.Mixed,
idRdv:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Rdv'}
});
```

And another Schema:

```
var RdvSchema = new Schema({
_idRdv:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
person:{type: Schema.Types.Mixed, ref:'Person'}
});

var Person= mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
var Rdv = mongoose.model('Rdv',RdvSchema);
```

When I add datas:

```
var person1= new Person({
Name: 'Jean',
_idRdv: rdv1._idRdv <--- this value isn't defined yet so it won't pass it to mongo

var rdv1 = new Rdv({
_idRdv: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
person: person1.Name
});
```

When I add datas to these Schemas I'll have a problem with patient not receiving the _idRdv value since patient has been created before Rdv.

Is there a way to make it possible to have the _idRdv filled too ?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a line at the end: `person1._idRdv = rdv1._idRdv;`?

Comment: Lol, Yeah the simplest things... thanks dude :)